# Popup is collapsing appbarlayout when showed

Tags: android, popupmenu

I am trying to show pop up using overflow button in fragment. Code is as follow

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
                MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_now_plying, popup.getMenu());
                popup.show();
        }
```

Why it is collapsing my appbar layout? help is appreciated

Comment: No, I am not using overflow menu button in toolbar or action bar. I am using it in fragment below toolbar. When clicked on it, it is collapsing the appbar (which consists of couple of toolbars).

Answer (score 0):

Use it:
   `PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view, Gravity.RIGHT);`

Comment: Can you give a better explanation of what the difference is here and why your way will work?